# In how many ways can a group of students be seated in a row, the students from the same class must alternate

Tags: algorithm, permutation

There are `M` students from `N` classes, `A[i]` is the number of students from `class_i`, `sum(A[i]) == M`. All these students will sit in a row with `M` seats, and there are no 2 students from the same class sit next to each other.

How many valid ways can these `M` students be seated in a row?

For example, 
if N = 2, A = {1, 2},
the output should be 2;

if N = 2, A = {1, 3},
the output should be 0;

if N = 3, A = {1, 2, 3},
the output should be 120.

Technical Specification:
N < 47;
A[i] < 47;
sum(A) < 447;

if the output is greater than 1000000007, than output (result % 1000000007).

Comment: _"no 2 students from the same class sit next to each other."_ only means _"must alternate"_ for `N == 2`

Comment: If you were not aware of what permuations are, [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations) may help you with what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure this belongs on stackoverflow, and it looks suspiciously like homework, but have an upvote for an interesting question.

Comment: If one of the A[i] is greater than M/2+1, the answer is 0... it'll be hard to get the correct formula for this.

Comment: if we assume all classes have same number of children lets say n , and n=M/N, then number of valid way for m students to be seated in row should be  (n!)^n * n

Comment: As @Vesper hints at, this is a much more complex problem than it may seem, because there are cases where there is no solution (M=12, N=2, A={10,2}), as well as cases with many solutions, and possibly even cases with a unique solution. There's not likely a simple closed-form formula or algorithm for it.

Comment: @Eric it's a problem of a online programming contest, I spent much effort on it, but with no result.

Comment: you shouldn't be using SO to participate in a contest.  Seems pretty blatantly wrong, unless the contest is over.

Comment: @RandyHoward yes, exactly, the contest was over at that time.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might not be optimal, but I think it is a good start.

There are two components to this problem:

1. Labeling each seat to a class (X ways)
2. Assigning a seat to a student (Y ways)

Final answer is equal to X*Y.

Part 2 is very easy. Y = A(1)!*A(2)!*...*A(N)!

Calculating first part is tricky though. You can use DP to solve it. Complexity = N*A(1)*A(2)*...*A(N) (which is too expensive for my taste)

DP problem is:

F(a1,a2,..,an,last_letter=1) = F(a1-1,a2,..,an,last_letter!=1)+F(a1,a2-1,..,an,last_letter!=1)+...+F(a1,a2,..,an-1,last_letter!=1)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following python code:

```
import math

mem={}

def get_id(A, forbidden):
    count = {}
    for a in A:
        if a<>forbidden:
            n = A[a]
            count[n] = count.get(n,0)+1
    return frozenset( [A.get(forbidden, 0)] + count.items() )

def class_seatings(A, forbidden=None):
    if sum(A.values())==1:
        if forbidden in A:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
    ssum = 0
    for a in A:
        if a <> forbidden:
            n = A[a]
            A2 = dict(A) 
            if n==1:
                del A2[a]
            else:
                A2[a] -= 1
            id = get_id(A2, a)
            if id not in mem:
                mem[id] = class_seatings(A2, a)
            cs = mem[id]
            ssum += cs
    return ssum

def student_seatings(A):
    assert all(map(lambda x: x>0, A.values()))
    facts = map(lambda x: math.factorial(x), A.values())
    mult = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, facts, 1)
    return mult*class_seatings(A) % 1000000007
```

It looks like it gets the basic cases right:

```
>>> student_seatings( {1:1, 2:2} )
2
>>> student_seatings( {1:1, 2:2, 3:3} )
120
>>> student_seatings( {1:1, 2:3} )
0
>>> student_seatings( {1:2, 2:2} )
8
```

However the basic memoization scheme using `mem` and `get_id` starts to crumble before the requirements you mention. To see this, watch the progression

```
mem={}
for upper in range(2,11):
    A = dict( (x,x) for x in range(1,upper) )   
    print len(A), student_seatings(A)
    print len(mem)
```

which yields

```
1 1
0
2 2
4
3 120
20
4 309312
83
5 579005048
329
6 462179000
1286
7 481882817
5004
8 678263090
19447
9 992777307
75581
```

Anyone care to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

First notice that given a valid seating arrangement for input list `A` such that `sum(A)=n`, it is easy to compute the number of valid seating arrangements when a new class of size `m` arrives:

- Fit the `m` new students in all possible `n+1` valid positions (there are `n` old students, which means `n+1` valid positions). This is the exact definition of combinations, and there are `C(n+1,m)` such combinations.
- Then permute the `m` new students to get all possible valid seating arrangements.

Therefore, the arrival of the new class of size `m` has multiplied the number of valid seating arrangements by `C(n+1,m) * m!`. This suggests the following algorithm (in Python):

```py
import math
import scipy.misc

def f(A) :
    if len(A) == 2 :
        a,b = A
        if a == b  : 
        # two solutions o+o+ and +o+o without order consideration, then multiply by 2! * 2! to get all possible orders within classes
            return math.factorial(a) * math.factorial(b) * 2 
        elif abs( a - b ) == 1 : 
        # o+o+o without order consideration, then multiply by 2! * 3! to get all possible orders within classes
            return math.factorial(a) * math.factorial(b)
        else : # no solution
            return 0
    else : # the number of valid arrangement is multiplied by C(n+1,m) * m!
        return sum( f(A[:i]+A[i+1:]) * scipy.misc.comb( sum(A)-ai + 1, ai ) * math.factorial(ai) for i, ai in enumerate(A) )
```

Let's check that we get the same results as the OP's examples:

```py
f( [ 1,2 ] )
2

f( [ 1,3 ] )
0

f( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )
120.0
```

It works! Let's try with three classes of 30 students:

```py
f( [ 30, 30, 30 ] )
2.6058794190003256e+115 # this is greater than the number of baryons in the universe!
```